# How do I make something happen in my windows phone 7 app only once?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I need to do something only once (in my case creating an instance of a class). The closest thing I can find is putting it in the PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded event handler, or at the top of MainPage.xaml. But this doesn't work for me because I have other pages in my app, so if I navigate from another page back to the MainPage it executes that code again.

Thanks, David

Comment: once per application or once per session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a new project, you will find an `App.xaml.cs` file added to your project. Here you can add code that is executed at various points in your application lifecycle. You can add code to the method thar handles the `Launching` event:

```
// Code to execute when the application is launching (eg, from Start)
// This code will not execute when the application is reactivated
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
   // your code goes here
}
```

This code will be executed just once when you application launches.

Comment: So if I create an instance of a class here, and that classes constructor needs to access a listbox on MainPage.xaml, will it be able to? It seems like all of the stuff on MainPage.xaml wouldn't have loaded yet.

Comment: @davekats that sounds awful, you want an application-level class to have access to a UI control on a specific page. I think you should re-consider your design. Have a read about the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 1):

What you need (I assume) is a singleton class:

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    private Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton GetInstance()
    {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Now calling `Singleton.GetInstance()` from anywhere guarantees that you will get the same instance everytime.

Comment: Either the code will need to be in the singleton's ctor, or an `HasExecuted` flag to ensure code isn't re-run. This singleton implementation isn't threadsafe in .NET, not sure about Windows Phone 7.

Comment: @SuperUser: It is thread-safe. The static init at the beginning is guaranteed to be executed in a single thread.

Comment: @Tudor I get an error on GetInstace() that says Method must have a return type?

Comment: @Tudor you're right, mea culpa. I got confused between thread-saftey and laziness because of the issue caused by `beforefieldinit` http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/BeforeFieldInit.aspx